# validator could not be imported Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting

Tags: python, django, validation, passwords, computer-science

i made validators.py and added my custom password validators like check for uppercase and special characters and after that i added those in my auth password validators in my settings.py like this

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
'OPTIONS': {
'max_similarity': 0.7,
'user_attributes': ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email")
}
},
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
'OPTIONS': {
'min_length': 8,
}
},
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
\# custom coded validators
{
'NAME': 'app1.validators.UppercaseValidator',
},
{
'NAME': 'app1.validators.SpecialCharValidator',
},
]
```

this is my forms.py

`

```
from django import forms from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password class SignupForm(forms.Form):
     firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)     
     lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)     
     email = forms.EmailField()
     username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
     password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, validators=[validate_password])`
```

and while signing up im getting this error

`ImproperlyConfigured at /signup/ The module in NAME could not be imported: app1.validators.UppercaseValidator. Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting.`

Any help is appreciated

before it is giving me error based on validators that django has bydefault but after adding my own validator it giving me error i mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running my django instance
It works fine with version (3, 2, 19, 'final', 0) while it brokes with version (4, 1, 7, 'final', 0).
Here my uppercase code:

```
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class UppercaseValidator:
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z."),
            code='password_no_upper',
        )

def get_help_text(self):
    return _(
        "Your password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z."
    )
```

Here my settings.py:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
   # custom coded validators
   {'NAME': 'users.validators.UppercaseValidator',},
   ... 
]
```

So I moved the validation into the serializer.py, commenting the code in settings.py and it worked.
Here the code of my serializer.py:

```
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    def validate(self, data):
        user = User(**data)
        password = data.get('password')
        try:
            if not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
               raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z.")
        except Exception as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, A-Z.")
```

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

to

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

`ugettext` has been deprecated and replaced with `gettext` in [django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/releases/3.0/#deprecated-features-3-0).

Comment: A reference  to doc would help?